# How to set thead in vertical in datatable?

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

I have used jquery datatable,

HTML Code

```
<table id="result_table" class="display table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Activation Status</th>
                        <th>Recent Login</th>
                        <th>Total No. of login</th>
                        <th>Avg No. of login/day</th>
                        <th>Total No. of Exports</th>
                        <th>Total No. of access</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Activation Status</th>
                        <th>Recent Login</th>
                        <th>Total No. of login</th>
                        <th>Avg No. of login/day</th>
                        <th>Total No. of Exports</th>
                        <th>Total No. of access</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

and I have to load the table data in ajax call in JSON datatype here my PHP code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){
    $name = $row['first_name'];
    $name_string = "<a edit_id='name_".trim($name)."' href='#' onClick=\"click_today('{$name}');\"  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>{$name}</a>";
    
    //onClick=\"click_today('{$name}');\"
    $result_array[] = array($row['id'], $name_string, $row['last_name'], $row['job_title'], $row['salary'],"-","-","-");
}
echo json_encode($result_array);
```

acutually my result is (sample output)
[image]

but i want following image output in datatable
[image]

I don't know how to implement vertical header in jquery data table I am always using horizontal thead but now I need vertical header because of needed pls share ur suggestion or solution

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make this kind of output from **server side[php] only** then 
  to assign datatable. I had also face this problem but I make way from server side
  and another way is also there you change your expected format using **PIVOT Table**
  using database